# Launch maven plugin and attach debugger on VS Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, maven-plugin

I want to run a maven plugin in debug mode on VS Code, right now I'm launching the plugin using the following command on a terminal:

`mvnDebug org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:1.9.7:run`

Then I do attach the VS Code debugger using this settings:

```json
{
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Tomcat Debug",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "8000"
},
```

Is there any way I can launch the maven plugin with debugger directly on VS Code?

(using launch.json, not the vs code maven plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `mainClass` and select the name in debug option, click the green triangle button then you can get the maven project run and debugging:

[image]

Comment: It's a WAR packaged application, it does not contain a main class

Comment: VS Code docs mentions that users can debug it in **Tomcat Servers** but no introductions about debugging war packages in launch.json. see [work with Tomcat](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty#_tomcat)